# Определить количество голосов, отданных каждой партии

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Здравствуйте. Не могу решить задачу. Питону только учусь, буду благодарен за помощь :)
Дан текстовый файл, содержащий информацию о количестве голосовавших за каждую партию в городах:

(ниже примерный вид файла .txt который надо читать питоном)

```
Москва           ЕР    180000
Санкт-Петербург  КПРФ  11000
Екатеринбург     ЛДПР  15000
Киров            ЕР    14000
Надым            КПРФ  110000
```

(где: Москва - город(не важен), ЕР-Партия, 180000-кол-во голосов)
Определить количество голосов, отданных каждой партии.

У меня получилось отсортировать одинаковые города, но на выходе получаю словарь, где в значении список... как получить сумму каждого значения словаря?

Файл vote.txt

```
Екатеринбург ЕР 180000
Екатеринбург КПРФ 22000
Первоуральск КПРФ 11000
Первоуральск ЕР 1000
Екатеринбург ЛДПР 15000
```

Код:

```
temp = []
file = open('vote.txt', 'r') 
for line in file.read().split('\n'): 
    temp.append(line) 

file.close()

list = [] 
for i in temp: 
    a = i.split()
    list.append(a)
    a.remove(a[0]) 

d = {key: [] for key, _ in list}
for key, value in list:
    d[key].append(int(value))

print(d)
```

Comment: могут быть города или партии с пробелом в имени, и тогда отпределить где кончается город, а где начинается партия, будет невозможно

Comment: Город не важен. Я его вообще вырезал.

Comment: код несоответствует файлу примера

Comment: Скинул мой vote.txt,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get(file):
    for (city, party, rate) in map(str.split, open(file)):
        yield party, rate

result = {}

for (party, rate) in get('example.txt'):
    if party in result:
        result[party] += int(rate)
    else:
        result[party] = int(rate)

print(result)  # {'ЕР': 181000, 'КПРФ': 33000, 'ЛДПР': 15000}
```

Comment: Блин. Спасибо вам) Я вообще не в тот лес уплыл.

Comment: @RacCoon: вместо простого словаря, [удобно `collections.Counter` здесь использовать.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781199/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Используя [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('votes.txt',  names=['city', 'party', 'votes'],
                   delim_whitespace=True, header=None, index_col=False)
print(df.groupby('party').sum())
```

Результат:

```
        votes
party        
ЕР     194000
КПРФ   121000
ЛДПР    15000
```

---

Используя только стандартную библиотеку:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('votes.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():  # skip blank lines
            _, party, votes = line.split()
            counter[party] += int(votes)

for party, votes in counter.most_common():
    print("{:<4} {:>6}".format(party, votes))
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/Rj0b10):

```
ЕР   194000
КПРФ 121000
ЛДПР  15000
```

Comment: Pandas это плюс ;)